# How can I omit a folder when merging a branch to another branch in git

Tags: git, git-merge

I am currently working on a project using Flask and Flask Migrate. I have two branches, one for developing and the other production branch. I made a change in my models.py by creating a new model (table) in my **development branch**. Then I run `flask db migrate` to generate migration scripts in the **development branch** after which I run `flask db upgrade` to apply changes I made in my schema. Now I want to merge my **development branch** into my **production branch** while omitting the migration folder so that I can run `flask db migrate` then followed `flask db upgrade` in my **production branch**. In summary I don't want the migration folder of the **development branch** to be merged into that of **production branch** during merging process. I am using different databases for the two branches.

I have tried running `git merge --no-commit` but I could not achieve my purpose with that.

Comment: The migration folder shouldn't be committed in the development branch in the first place. It's not part of your software; it's an external tool used to help *test* your changes.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this, I believe the best solution is to use a `.gitignore` file. In this file, you would place the name of the directory you want ignored by your commits and merges.

An example is common in NodeJS projects, you want to ignore the node_modules directory due to its size. The `.gitignore` file to accomplish this would look like:

.gitignore

```
node_modules/
```

Here is where you can read more about `.gitignore` files and their syntax: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Edit:

This is works in the case where you have not staged your changes or committed. If you delete the generated files and commit before adding the `.gitignore`, then you will be able to ignore the generated files when merging changes between branches regardless of how you stage files. (Helpful if you tend to utilize `git add .` to stage all of your changed files at once.

Comment: If the files in the folder are untracked, there's no problem with the merge. If they are tracked, `.gitignore` won't help.